# react-router v4 routerConfig with huge data object for each route

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have a routerConfig as below with each route having huge data object which is used to render the data in the route. And routes are nested approx with `depth=4` for about `166` routes. `routerConfig` is available in redux state across application. This routeConfig is immutable and set on app initialisation.

```
[{
  path: '/category1',
  name: 'Category1',
  dataObj: {
    // ... very huge data object
  },
  childRoutes: [{
    path: '/subcategory1',
    name: 'Sub Category1',
    dataObj: {
      // ... very huge data object
    }
  },
  {
    // ... other child routes with nested children
  }]
},
{
  // ... other routes with nested children
}]
```

**Approach 1**

Attaching `dataObj` for each route to the Container props and use it later in the Component render directly.

```
// routes.js
routerConfig.map(route => (
  <Route exact path={route.path} render={props => (
    <Container {...props} dataObj={route.dataObj} />
  )}
  />
)
});
/// ... nested routes are handled by recursive loop

// Container.js
render() {
  const {
    dataObj
  } = this.props
  /// ... use dataObj for rendering data
}
```

**Approach 2**

Fetching routerConfig from redux state in Container and filtering out the dataObj based on path while `render or componentDidMount`.

```
// router.js
routerConfig.map(route => (
  <Route exact path={route.path} component={Container}/>
)
});
/// ... nested routes are handled by recursive loop

// Container.js
render() { // can be componentDidMount and set in state
  const {
   routeConfig,
   match: { path }
  } = this.props

  const dataObj = () => {
    // extract dataObj by filtering routeConfig with path
  }

  /// ... use dataObj for rendering data
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  routeConfig: state.application.routeConfig
})
```

I want to know which is better approach in handling data attached to each route. Or any other better way to treating the data.

Having `166` static routes recommended or better to have fewer (50) routes with params?

Comment: Since `dataObj` will never change, so assgin it only once to the `Container` is sufficient, no need to extract it each time `Container` renders, so I think the first approach is better. Use the first approach could enhance performance in 1. you could use functional component, because no need to connect to redux; 2. you could eliminate the (little, I guess) impact of extracting object.

Comment: @MarsonMao thanks. But there will be like 70+ routes inside `<Switch />`, each route will have a `Container` with `dataObj` attached to it. So, will there be not much performance issue with this approach?